# "gem install" on vagrant provision setup.sh from shell with rbenv

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm using this vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  ...bla bla bla bla bla...

    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/setup.sh", privileged: false

end
```

In my *setup.sh* I have:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --yes git-all libreadline-dev build-essential curl git m4 python-setuptools ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev

yes | ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"

echo PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc    
export PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH
brew doctor
```

then I have:

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
brew update
brew upgrade

echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
rbenv init

rbenv install 2.3.0
rbenv global 2.3.0
rbenv local 2.3.0
rbenv versions

gem install bundler
```

but I receive this error:

```
==> default: ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) ==> default: Permission denied - /var/lib/gems`
```

How can I install "bundler" and other "gems" with my setup script?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to run sudo in a script, but try sudoing the script itself with

```
$ sudo ./script.sh
```

and take all your 'sudos' out of your sh script.

Next change

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/setup.sh", privileged: false
```

to

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/setup.sh", privileged: true
```

This way sudo is only unlocked for the file, and it has control for whatever you are doing.

If this is a new file in the machine, you may need to use

```
chmod +x ./script.sh
```

for your os to execute it properly. From what I see, things should work okay unless you have accidentally provisioned your vm twice in which you may want to override it. You also can try running each command yourself to see if it is an isolated issue outside of vagrant.

**edit:** 
The main issue is that the /var/lib/gems directory is own by root, so by whatever means get that under the sudo command.

**edit:** Massive clarity.

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: @JohnSam The main issue is that /var/ is owned by root, so just get that under sudo.

Comment: keeping things under the user so with `privileged: false` and just turn `sudo gem install bundler` would work; if sudo does not find gem, you can indicate full path as `sudo /wherever ruby is installed/gem install bundler`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Works well enough. There's just a lot of commands that require sudo, and I have had issues before with doing it that way.